# Unbound error - unbound.service: Start request repeated too quickly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unbound

I am new using unbound.

I have a network 192.168.50.1 to 192.168.50.240. And I'd like to use DoH for non cache data.

my conf file:

```
# Unbound configuration file for Debian.
#
# See the unbound.conf(5) man page.
#
# See /usr/share/doc/unbound/examples/unbound.conf for a commented
# reference config file.
#
# The following line includes additional configuration files from the
# /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d directory.
include: "/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/*.conf"

server:

    forward-zone:
        name: "."
        forward-addr: https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query

    directory: "/etc/unbound"

    username: unbound

    verbosity: 2

    interface: 0.0.0.0

    prefetch: yes

    access-control: 192.168.50.0/24 allow
    access-control: 127.0.0.1/24 allow

    hide-identity: yes
    hide-version: yes

    remote-control:
        control-enable: no

    control-interface: 127.0.0.1
    control-port: 8953
```

What is wrong in my conf file?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check the logs.

Answer (score 1):

`directory` should be under `server`, not under `forward-zone` (it does not matter if the lines are indented). Also, `forward-addr` should be an IP address, not a URL (I'm not sure if Unbound can act as a DoH client at all).